# Parse Google Map Json with Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a google Mpa Json url
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?&origins=2020%20E%20main%20ST&destinations=100%20E%20Main%20St%20,Edmond,Ok&mode=driving&sensor=false

that gives me

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "100 East Main Street, Edmond, OK 73034, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "2020 East Main Street, Lamar, AR 72846, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "410 km",
                  "value" : 409567
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 hours 49 mins",
                  "value" : 13759
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

i am trying to parse it using

```
  function callGoogle(inputOrigin, inputDst, inputMode)
      {
      $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?', { origins: inputOrigin, destinations: inputDst, mode: inputMode,  sensor: false }, function (data) {

                $.each(data, function (i, item) {               
                    console.log(item.rows.elements.distance.text);

                });


            });

        }
```

but i am getting erros. how do i get the 97.8 or 97766 from this json using jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
var data = {
    "destination_addresses": ["1000 Chopper Circle, Denver, CO 80204, USA"],
    "origin_addresses": [
        "2121 East Mulberry Street, Fort Collins Nursery, Fort Collins, CO 80524, USA"
    ],
    "rows": [
        {
            "elements": [
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "97.8 km",
                        "value": 97766
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "57 mins",
                        "value": 3449
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
};

alert(data.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value);
```

Note, the data has two arrays, I am using [0] to get the first item in each.

Comment: Should explain to OP why he has to declare an index of the array to get the values he wants. Otherwise he'll just be back in the future with the same questions regarding a new JSON string. +1 regardless.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - I added a note.